# Cannot add a contact on Skype

Tags: browser, skype

I can't add a contact on Skype. When I click the "Add contact", I get a blank page. What's wrong? How to fix it?

After installing IE8, now it becomes: after I click "add contact", I get an alert icon and text like "Check your connection

You don't seem to have an active internet connection.

Please check your connection and try again."

Comment: A blank page? - Are you doing this via the Skype application or via a webpage?

Comment: Via the application.

Comment: Well, first thing as always, did you try logging on and off and is Skype up to date?

Comment: What do you mean by "try logging on and off"? The Skype version is 5.10.0.115.

Comment: I would sign out and completely shutdown Skype and restart

Answer (score 0):

One of possible reasons for such behaviour can also be that **Content Adviser** is activated in your Internet Explorer.

[Content advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-Content-Advisor-to-help-block-inappropriate-web-content) blocks pages with no rating or a rating too high.Skype add user is a website that it references.

I was able to fix my skype while keeping the Content Advisor on simply by going into the content advisor settings and adding (Skype's Server IP Address) into the acception list. Add Users works fine.

Solution for [Cannot Add a Contact](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Cannot-Add-a-Contact-Solution/td-p/429025).

Hope it helps.